# Regular Expression, JEditorPane, Self-closing tags

Tags: java, regex, swing, jeditorpane

I'm am using JEditorPane to render basic HTML.  But it renders self-closing tags incorrectly, specifically br tags, e.g. <br /> is bad but <br> is good.  I would like to use String.replaceAll(regex, "<br>") to fix the HTML, where regex is a regular expression matching any self-closing br tag with case-insensitivity and zero to infinity number of spaces between the "r" and the "/" (e.g., <br/>, <BR/>, <br />, <Br     />, etc.).

Thanks to any regular expression experts who can solve this!

Comment: `<br />` is invalid HTML, anyway. And `<BR/>` would be invalid XHTML. Wouldn't it be easier to craft the underlying HTML in a correct way instead of hack-fixing it afterwards with regexes?

Comment: My source HTML is from the late 90's.  Indeed, before using HtmlCleaner to clean and extract fragments to store a database MOST of the br tags are not closed properly.  But THEN I need to use JEditorPane to render it, so it needs to be converted back to pre-HTML 4 standards!  And of course, we may have to use Flying Saucer or some other rendering solution in the future, so it's best to keep it close to standard in the database and fix it on the fly for JEditorPane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
<[bB][rR]\s*/>
```

- `<` : To match a literal <
- `[bB]` : A char class that matches
  either `b` or `B`
- `[rR]` : A char class that matches
  either `r` or `R`
- `\s` : Any one white space
- `\s*` : zero or more white spaces.

If you want to allow only a space for a white space you can use:

```
<[bB][rR] */>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply and explanation!  I will test it now and mark as answered if it works!